# How can I access a public folder on Windows 10 from Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) anonymously?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, file-sharing, ubuntu-18.04

I have set up a shared directory on Windows 10 (18362) that allows guest access. Accessing it from another Windows machine works, no password is needed. However, when I try to access it from my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, it keeps asking for password (using Nautilus). When I try to use smbclient, it goes like this (Cesnecka.local is the Windows computer's local DNS address and pokus is the shared folder):

```
$ smbclient -L //Cesnecka.local/pokus  -m SMB3 -U guest
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter DOMA\guest's password: 

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
        C$              Disk      Default share
        IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
        pokus           Disk      
        Users           Disk      
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
Connection to Cesnecka.local failed (Error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND)
Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

As can be seen, it asks me for the password and then lists some shared folders on the Windows host. Any idea why it might work from Windows and not from Ubuntu?

As for the Windows host:

1. I turned off Password-protected sharing in Advanced sharing settings, I set permissions,
2. I set the Function Discovery Provider Hosts and Function Discovery Provider Publication services to start up automatically
3. in properties of the folder, under "Sharing" tab, when I click on "Share...", the folder is shared with the Guest user
4. in properties of the folder, under "Sharing" tab, in "Advanced sharing", under "Permissions", Everyone and "Guest (Cesnecka\Guest)" have all permissions set to allow
5. in properties of the folder, under "Security" tab, "Guest (Cesnecka\Guest)" has all permissions set to allow.

Comment: Did you set the permissions of the folder to `Everyone` within Windows?  "ailed to connect with SMB1" - Windows 10 comes with SMBv1 disabled out of the box.

Comment: Yes, as per point 4. I also now tried from my android phone from VLC, which has a in-built samba browser and there it works. I am asked for login credentials but when I filled the user with "HOME;guest" and left password blank, it showed me the content of the folder. So I guess the problem might me more with Ubuntu itself? But what might be causing it?